# How to access the remote desktop of SLED 11 sp3

Tags: linux, vnc, suse

All, I am trying to establish the remote desktop access to my SUSE Linux from windows 7.
I install the GNome as the graphic environment for SUSE. And I can started the vnc server in the SUSE. and I can use the UltraVNC viewer to connect in windows 7. But It only shows the command console with the successful connection to SUSE. I want the GUI remote desktop of SUSE.

How to make it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

getidisp
or,
export DISPLAY=server:0.0

This command will export the display of remote desktop in local server
You have to run this command after entering into the remote server shell using rsh or rlogin